# Having problems running python script even when putty is closed

Tags: linux, bots

So basically, I have a bot I'm running, and I would like for it to keep running even when I exit putty.

I've tried using `nohup python bot.py &` but it still ends the python bot when I close the putty program. I've also tried using a run.sh file with `/usr/bin/nohup bot.py &` inside it. but it won't work :( is there something else I'm missing?

I have also made sure the run.sh is a executable as some other forums have suggested, and I still get `can't open run`

I'm kinda new to the linux terminal.

if you guys could help me out that would be awsome :)

Comment: are you sure the command is not running?  It could be that you are just not seeing your output

Comment: It literally doesn't want to run at all. it's really weird. the syntax seems sooo simple, yet it's not doing what it should, and everytime i exit putty it stops the bot.

Comment: O like, that... this is not a good answer, but you can try using `screen`.

Comment: So how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to detach the terminal so that when you exit, it is still running. You can use `screen` or `tmux` or some other multiplexer.

Here is how to do with [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html):

```
screen -S mybot -m -d /usr/bin/python /path/to/bot.py
```

- `-S` give the session a name (this is useful if you want to attach later. `screen -D -R mybot`)
- `-m` always create a new session
- `-d` detach (launch the program, but then detach the terminal returning you to the prompt)

Comment: but shouldn't `nohup` be able to do it on its own? Furthermore `screen` often is not installed by default. If the OP doesn't have admin rights it won't help anyways.

Comment: Thanks mate, Well i've tried that, but... it never worked for me. So, i am using another users suggestion with using tmux and so far it's working perfectly.